# Virtuoso SPARQL execution time

Tags: sparql, virtuoso

I am running a Virtuoso Open Source Server version 07.20.3217.

I am storing triples in there. However, when doing certain SPARQL queries, I get the following error message:

```
Virtuoso 42000 Error The estimated execution time 0 (sec) exceeds the limit of 3000 (sec).
```

It is not the first time it happens to me. Normally I try to re-write the query and the problem is solved. However, this time the estimated time is 0. Besides, I am not able to re-write the query to avoid this error.

The server is only accessed locally by me, so I would not have any problem enabling queries that take a lot of time.

What I am asking is: Is it any configuration file or similar in Virtuoso, where I can set a higher limit than 3000 sec per query?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: You can set a higher execution time limit in the `virtuoso.ini` file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a server-side timeout, `MaxQueryExecutionTime`, set in the `[SPARQL]` section of the Virtuoso `INI` file, as [discussed in the product documentation](http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/anytimequeries/).

ObDisclaimer: [OpenLink Software](https://www.openlinksw.com/) produces [Virtuoso](https://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/), and employs me.